# Diophantine approximation and the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, computational-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

My question is whether something I've noticed is well-known. It seems like it must be, but I've been unable to find any references that describe what is outlined below.

Given real $x$ and irrational $c$, suppose that you want to find an integer $n$ such that
$$x\approx nc + m,$$
where $m$ is an integer. When $x=0$, this is easily solved using the Euclidean algorithm/continued fractions. The *existence* of solutions also falls under the broad category of "Kronecker's theorem."

To *find* such solutions use the Euclidean algorithm. The Euclidean algorithm is given by defining $r_{-1} = c$, $r_0 = 1$ and
$$r_k = r_{k-2} - q_kr_{k-1},$$
where $q_k = \lfloor r_{k-2}/r_{k-1}\rfloor$.
Call the $r_k$ the *residuals*. In addition, set $x_{-1} = 1$, $x_0 = 0$, $y_{-1}
= 0$, $y_0=1$ and define
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_k &=& x_{k-2} - q_k x_{k-1} \\
y_k &=& y_{k-2} - q_k y_{k-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

One way to find solutions to
$$x\approx nc + m$$
is by "chipping away" at $x$ via the residuals. That is, we know (Bézout) that
$$r_k = x_k c + y_k.$$
So, if we can find integral $s_k$ such that $\sum s_kr_k \approx x$, then $n= \sum s_k x_k$ is a solution. To find the $s_k$, set $e_0 = x$ and define $s_k = \lfloor e_k/r_k\rfloor$ and $e_k = e_{k-1}-s_k r_k$. Since $r_k\rightarrow 0$, this approximation can be made arbitrarily tight.

The same idea can be extended to higher dimensions by using a higher-dimensional Euclidean algorithm. Also, in the 1-dimensional case, it's not hard to put an upper bound on $n$.

I've been looking for references that described the algorithm above, but have come up empty. There is a paper by Borwein & Borwein (*On the generating function of the integer part* $[n\alpha+\gamma]$, J. Number Theory, 1993) that has an algorithm to find such $n$, but their algorithm is much more complicated. I've also recently become aware of the PSLQ algorithm, and the algorithm above seems to live in the same "idea space" as PSLQ, but there's no obvious relationship between the two.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but the LLL algorithm which is base on the Euclidean algorithm maybe  look as a high dimensional generalization of the Euclidean algorithm  in one dimensional, and in particular it can help to find a lattice in some  sense is minimal.